# Haskell getter of data type

Tags: haskell

Basically, I have 2 different structures - Point and Cell. Since there is an aggregation between them, I would like to somehow get the value of the Point just by having the cell - let's say at a moment, I only have a cell but I wish to get its location.
Like this `a = Wall(Point(1,2)`. Can I somehow get it? Like `a.point`? And if so, can I get `x` and `y` somehow like this?  `a.point.x`.

```
data Point = Point(Int, Int) -- y, x
instance Show Point where
  show (Point(x, y)) = "(" ++ show x ++ "," ++ show y ++ ")"

data Cell = Wall(Point) | Path(Point) | Start(Point) | End(Point)
instance Show Cell where
  show (Wall(Point(x, y))) = "X"
  show (Path(Point(x, y))) = "("++show x ++ "," ++ show y ++ ")"
  show (Start(Point(x, y))) = "S"
  show (End(Point(x, y))) = "E"
```

Comment: (1) You probably want to define `data CellType = Wall | Path | Start | End` then `data Cell = Cell CellType Point`. (2) You can use `lens` to write `a^.point.x` (assuming you have the right lenses defined).

Comment: Again, `data Point = Point Int Int` would be sufficient, as would `data Cell = Wall Point | Path Point | Start Point | End Point`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I think you're confused about `data` declaration syntax:

```
data Point = Point(Int, Int)
```

This is a data constructor that takes a single tuple argument, i.e. you think the parens are some kind of syntax for application. We can ask ghci:

```
Prelude> data Point = Point(Int, Int)
Prelude> :t Point
Point :: (Int, Int) -> Point
```

What you actually want is:

```
Prelude> data Point = Point Int Int
Prelude> :t Point
Point :: Int -> Int -> Point
```

The second piece you're missing is called *record syntax*, which allows you to name the two `Int` fields above.

```
data Point = Point { x :: Int, y :: Int }
```

This brings into scope two functions `x` and `y` that can extract the piece of data you're interested in:

```
Prelude> data Point = Point { x :: Int, y :: Int }
Prelude> let p = Point 2 3
Prelude> :t x
x :: Point -> Int
Prelude> x p
2
Prelude> y p
3
```

You can do the same for `Wall` and then `point . x` will get you the function `Wall -> Int` you're looking for.

"lenses" are about making this sort of thing first-class, and are something I'd suggest not exploring right now. Definitely pick up a good haskell book and work through the first chapters carefully though.

Comment: I tried that and it seems it worked but I am still having trouble referring to the point of the Wall instance.  data Wall = Wall { point :: Point }. let w = Wall (Point 1 2) and when I type point . x w I get an error.

Comment: @GeorgeMorris `(.)` is a normal function, not special syntax, so you'll need to at least inspect its type (e.g. in ghci with `:t (.)`), and possibly look at the implementation to understand how to use it. For now do `point (x w)`. (and then pick up a haskell book)